# Verilog self checking testbench will not run? Building a simple ALU, this shouldn't be so hard

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl, modelsim, quartus

I am tasked with building an ALU.  However, I must not understand how the testbench should run. I have run other simple testbenches just fine.

1. code compiles (using quartus)
2. made a text file and turned it into a "test.tv" file
3. opened modelsim and added file
4. when I run it, is has an issue with the `y` and `zero` ports.

**Here is my code:**

```
module ALU(input [31:0] a,b,
input [2:0] f,
output reg [31:0] y ,
output reg zero);

always @(*) begin

    case(f)
      3'b000: y = a & b;  
      3'b001: y = a | b;  
      3'b010: y = a + b;    
      3'b011: y = 32'b0;    
      3'b100: y = a & ~b;
      3'b101: y = a | ~b;
      3'b110: y = a - b;
      3'b111: y = a < b;
     default: y = 32'b0;
  endcase
if(y==0)
    zero=1'b1;
else
    zero=1'b0;
end 
endmodule
```

//**********************

```
module testALU();
 reg clk;
 reg [31:0]a, b, yexpected;
 reg [2:0]f;
 reg [31:0]y; 
 reg zeroexpected;
 reg zero;
 reg[31:0] vectornum, errors;
 reg [100:0] testvectors[10000:0];

 ALU dut(a,b,f,yexpected,zeroexpected);

always
begin
    clk = 1; #5; clk = 0; #5;
end

initial
begin
    $readmemb("test.tv", testvectors);
    vectornum = 0; errors = 0;
end

always @(posedge clk)
begin
#1; {a,b,f,yexpected,zeroexpected} = testvectors[vectornum];
end

always @(negedge clk)
begin
if (y !== yexpected) begin
$display("Error: inputs = %b", {a,b,f});
$display(" outputs = %b (%b expected)", y, yexpected);
errors = errors + 1;
end

vectornum = vectornum + 1;
if (testvectors[vectornum] === 100'bx) begin
    $display("%d tests completed with %d errors", vectorum, errors);
    $stop;
 end
 end
endmodule
```

//*************************************

**ERROR:**

> ** Error: **(vsim-3043) Unresolved reference to 'vectorum'.
> Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /testALU File: C:/Users/prest/Desktop/Hardware Design/ALU/testALU.v Line: 40

> ** Error ** (suppressible): (vsim-3053) Illegal output or inout port connection for port 'y'.
> Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /testALU/dut File: C:/Users/prest/Desktop/Hardware Design/ALU/testALU.v Line: 11

> ** Error **(suppressible): (vsim-3053) Illegal output or inout port connection for port 'zero'.
> Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /testALU/dut File: C:/Users/prest/Desktop/Hardware Design/ALU/testALU.v Line: 11

**This is what my "test.tv" file looks like in binary**

```
> 00000000000000000000000000000000_00000000000000000000000000000000_010_00000000000000000000000000000000_1
> 00000000000000000000000000000000_11111111111111111111111111111111_010_11111111111111111111111111111111_0
> 00000000000000000000000000000000_01010101010101010101010101010101_010_01010101010101010101010101010101_0
```

I know this might seem stupid and simple, but I am really trying to learn this and obviously do not understand something. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors.

Change `vectorum` to `vectornum`.

Change your module instance connections so that there is no contention with the testbench signals for `zeroexpected` and `yexpected`.

Change the signals connected to the module outputs from `reg` to `wire`.

```
module testALU();
   reg clk;
   reg [31:0] a, b, yexpected;
   reg [2:0]  f;
   wire [31:0] y; 
   reg        zeroexpected;
   wire        zero;
   reg [31:0] vectornum, errors;
   reg [100:0] testvectors[10000:0];

   ALU dut(a,b,f,y,zero);

   always
     begin
        clk = 1; #5; clk = 0; #5;
     end

   initial
     begin
        $readmemb("test.tv", testvectors);
        vectornum = 0; errors = 0;
     end

   always @(posedge clk)
     begin
        #1; {a,b,f,yexpected,zeroexpected} = testvectors[vectornum];
     end

   always @(negedge clk)
     begin
        if (y !== yexpected) begin
           $display("Error: inputs = %b", {a,b,f});
           $display(" outputs = %b (%b expected)", y, yexpected);
           errors = errors + 1;
        end

        vectornum = vectornum + 1;
        if (testvectors[vectornum] === 100'bx) begin
           $display("%d tests completed with %d errors", vectornum, errors);
           $stop;
        end
     end
endmodule
```

This fixes all the compile errors.